# Zend - Site Configuration Data

Tags: zend-framework

For my zend application I need to read from the database some basic configuration data which should be available everywhere. I would like to read them and save it to session so that I wouldn't have to do so for every request. What is the best way I can get that done?

And also I would like to get the data from the 'Model' too and would feel very very uneasy to read from the session within the model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure, you want to store such important things in the session? You could also load the data from the database and save them in a file / Zend-Config-Object which exists for a specified time and gets updated than.

Another possibilty is Zend_Registry. This however needs to fetch the data each request.

Why don't you want to fetch the data each request from the database? You could easily use a controller-plugin which gets the job done for you. You write the code once and will never have to do something with that.

```
// This would be an example plugin-class...
class My_Config_Loader extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function preDispatch($request)
    {
         // Fetch data here... and save it into $data

         Zend_Registry::set('config', $data);
    }
}

// In your bootstrap...
$front = Zend_Controller_Front::getInstance();
$front->registerPlugin(new My_Config_Loader());

// Anywhere in your application
$config = Zend_Registry::get('config');
```

Comment: @faileN...it wont be that important a data...mostly like theme, google api key, domain url, admin mail id - things for view - so it would be best to save them in session...but at times i need them in the 'Model' layer to send mail or somethings like that...

Comment: what would it be like to get it from the session and save it in the registry? where should i do it? like for every request i would check the session if it is not there i will read it from the database and save it to the session and registry...if it is there in the session i will just get it from the session and save it in the registry...sounds like a hack :(

Comment: Well that was Zend_Registry (or the registry-pattern in general) invented for: To access data from everywhere in your application. So if you need the data in the controller, in the model and in the view I think it would be best, to store it in the registry and retrieve it from there. Of course you could save it in the session first, and then store the contents of the session in the registry. However I would only do it, if the query which fetches the data is extremely slow. If not, I would retrieve the data each request. Reason: What if a user visits your page surfs around and in the meantime..

Comment: ... an administrator changes the configuration in the database? The user would only the changes, when he starts a new session, with the updated data. So fetching the data each request would guarantee that the data is always up to date.

Comment: u have a point...now where do i do it...i mean to ensure a code is run for every request? controller plugin?

Comment: Yepp that's right. See my answer, there I got u an example for a controller-plugin (I forgot to extend the class `My_Config_Loader` with `Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract` - I fixed that now)